# How do i select a gin to use in making sloe gin?

Tags: alcohol, infusion, flavor

I have some sloes, collected from beside a bridleway in the depths of Essex. Naturally, i wish to make some sloe gin.

There are many gins. They can have quite different flavours: Gordon's is brute and junipery; Plymouth is oily; Tanqueray is spicy; Bombay Sapphire tastes like aftershave.

What flavours do i want in a gin which i am going to use to make sloe gin?

*(if you wish to interpret this question as a coded way of asking which gin i should use to make sloe gin, i will not stop you)*

Comment: Is there some reason to believe there is any factor at all other than personal preference at play here?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: Only that there are other matters of flavour combination where there is a 'right answer', or at least a consensus. For example, if i wanted to add a herb or spice to a chocolate dish, i suspect many people would suggest mint, chilli, or cardamom, and few would suggest basil, garlic, or cumin. Is there any reason to believe there is no factor that transcends personal preference at play here?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, I would recommend using mid-range gin for mixed drinks other than Gin & Tonic. The reason is that, except for GT, most mixed drinks involving gin are too heavily laced with other flavors for the more delicate flavor notes to shine through.

As such, any one of the ones you suggested would be fine for sloe gin, and anything else really comes down to personal preference.

*Source: Many years of experience as a bartender and drinker of mixed drinks.*